# Общение между потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Есть сокет-сервер. К нему подключаются два клиента по сокет-соединению. Как организовать общение между потоками (как передать данные или вызвать метод в другом потоке)?

Answer (score 1):

Способов передачи данных много как вариант рассмотрите класс [Pipe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) из пакета java.nio Данный класс представляет собой набор внутренних абстрактных классов и пару методов которые в сумме дают возможность работать с неким каналом для однонаправленной передачи битов.В момент начала передачи поток источник блокируется.Это один из самых быстрых способов работы между потоками.

Это всего лишь один из способов возможно реализовать обмен данными...Есть еще возможности собственной реализации через синхронизированные стеки или готовые [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) или [Exchanger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html)в общем выбор за Вами